# Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'BehaviorSubject<Dictionary>'

Tags: angular, angular6, ng-upgrade, npm-update

I am using BehaviorSubject for the communication between components. But when I try to subscribe, it is throwing an error as "Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'BehaviorSubject'."

```
 private dictionarySubject: BehaviorSubject<Dictionary> = new BehaviorSubject<Dictionary>(null);
```

In below code it is throwing an error

```
public subscribe(callback: (dicoes: Dictionary) => void) {
        this.dictionarySubject
            .subscribe((dico) => {
                if (dico === null) {
                    return;
                }
                callback(dico);
            });
    }
```

**Note : I have just migrated my angular application from version 5 to 6. Earlier it was working fine.**

Comment: Try `this.dictionarySubject.asObservable().subscribe(...)`.

Comment: Yes, It worked. Thank you

Comment: I've closed the question. Please refer the attached post for a Typescript specific solution.

Comment: Sure, Thank you